# How to GET different images in Flask without js?

Tags: python, html, flask

In my views.py I have this:

```
@app.route("/rnd", methods=["GET"])
def get_random_img():
    image = random.choice(images)
    full_path = "static/img/b/" + image
    return send_file(full_path)
```

And in my index.html I have this:

```
<main class="row">
    <div><img src="/rnd" class="responsive-img"></div>
    <div><img src="/rnd" class="responsive-img"></div>
    <div><img src="/rnd" class="responsive-img"></div>
    <div><img src="/rnd" class="responsive-img"></div>
    <div><img src="/rnd" class="responsive-img"></div>
```

And I added a js InfinityScroll. Everytime the user scrolls down, new `<div><img src="/rnd" class="responsive-img"></div>` will be append to the site. Everything works until here. But there is one big Problem, every image on the page is the same one? Is there a chance to solve this without touching the front-end with js? In my opinion I've seen similar technic on [robohash.org](https://robohash.org/), because no js is needed. I know the URL-Structure is different from mine, but maybe someone have an idea?

Comment: Can visit your link *robohash.org* ,BTW  what did you mean by said *without touching the front-end with js?*

Comment: on reddit i get some answers for js ajax calls. But my question is, if there is a solutions without js in the front-end?

Comment: *every image on the page is the same one* that's because your have the same request path, if you want to update it , the only way is change this every time!

Comment: but my route("/rnd") returns a random image path. What point ive overseen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to bind a rand url for your image src, like

```
@app.route("/rnd/<rand_num:int>", methods=["GET"])
def rnd():
    ...
    enter code here
```

and then modify your template as below:

```
<div><img src="url_for('rnd')" class="responsive-img"></div>
```

If you can put all your demo code here, maybe i can improve the answer!

Comment: hmm this helped but I try to explain it better. I want a API with the URL /rnd and every response is a random image. I dont want to customize the url.